# requestActivityTransitionUpdates never calls the registered BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I am coding a simple app that measures all available sensors of the android device (Wifi, BT, etc). One of them is the user activity (via ActivityRecognition API), but I can't make it works properly.

I code a class to do everything related to user activity. I want to get only 4 states and one attribute to store the current one:

```
var VEHICLE = "vehicle"
var WALKING = "walking"
var STILL = "still"
var UNKNOWN = "unknown"

private var current: String? = null
```

It also includes a BroadcastReceiver object to handle activity transitions:

```
private var recognitionHandler = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            val result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent)

            val activity = result.mostProbableActivity
            current = when(activity.type) {
                DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE,
                DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE -> VEHICLE
                DetectedActivity.WALKING,
                DetectedActivity.RUNNING -> WALKING
                DetectedActivity.STILL -> STILL
                else -> UNKNOWN
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class also have two methods to define the intent and request:

```
private fun createIntent() : PendingIntent {
    val intent = Intent(context, recognitionHandler.javaClass)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)

    context.registerReceiver(recognitionHandler, IntentFilter())
    return pendingIntent
}

private fun createRequest() : ActivityTransitionRequest {
    val types = listOf(
        DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE,
        DetectedActivity.WALKING,
        DetectedActivity.RUNNING,
        DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE,
        DetectedActivity.STILL
    )

    val transitions = mutableListOf<ActivityTransition>()
    types.forEach { activity ->
        transitions.add(
            ActivityTransition.Builder()
                .setActivityType(activity)
                .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                .build()
        )
    }

    return ActivityTransitionRequest(transitions)
}
```

And also one to start listening:

```
override fun start(onResult: (res: String?) -> Unit) {
    // ...

    intent = createIntent()
    val request = createRequest()
    ActivityRecognition.getClient(context)
        .requestActivityTransitionUpdates(request, intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("UserActivity Service info", "listening...")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.d("UserActivity Service error", e.toString())
            }

    // ...
}
```

The problem is that the `current` attribute is always null. I think I have some issues with intent or handler registration, but I have no idea where.

Does someone have any comments? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Does `onReceive()` get called?

Comment: Have you add permission to manifest? Here is an example:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/activity-recognition-transition/index.html

Comment: Did you figured out the problem?

Comment: @DavidWasser no, it doesn't.

Comment: @KaljaTolkki yes, it was already added

Comment: @KaljaTolkki no, still the same, I'm trying to monitor the intents

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If so, can you say how.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for awhile. I was finally able to get it to work by using this `PendingIntent`:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent("ACTION_PROCESS_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS"), Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S ? PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE : 0);
```

The flags at the end are important.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem. In this code from `createIntent()`:

```
val intent = Intent(context, recognitionHandler.javaClass)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)

context.registerReceiver(recognitionHandler, IntentFilter())
return pendingIntent
```

You return a `PendingIntent` that you use in the call to `requestActivityTransitionUpdates()`. However, that `PendingIntent` refers to a dynamically created inner class (your `BroadcastReceiver`) and Android cannot instantiate that class.

You also additionally call `registerReceiver()`, however you pass an **empty** `IntentFilter` in that call so the registered `BroadcastReceiver` is never called.

To fix the problem, you can either provide a correct`IntentFilter` that matches your `PendingIntent` OR you can refactor your `BroadcastReceiver` into a proper class (not a private inner class) and make sure that you've added the `BroadcastReceiver` to your manifest and make it publicly available (`exported="true"`).

Here's an example of how to do this using a `BroadcastReceiver`:

https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@betheleyo/implementing-android-s-new-activity-recognition-transition-api

Comment: Should the example work? I have cloned the repo and deployed it to real device, but I am not receiving any transitions. I can see from the logs that the registration was successful, but onReceive is not called (walked around for ~2min). Tested with two devices.